# java string replace ignore parts of string not in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have a list string below

```
Hello 123, [Derp]
         , [Derpa]
         , [derpb]
```

I tried...

```
//loop n bufferedreader stuff
string a = b.replaceAll("[Hello 123\\[\\]\\ ]", "")
```

what i got

```
Drp
Drpa
Drpb
```

What i want

```
Derp
Derpa
Derpb
```

I also tried to declare 2 bufferedreaders
the first one to hardcode ignore "Hellow 123" out of the string
and 2nd one without the hardcode
but same problem still occurs

Comment: BufferedReader has exactly nothing to do with it.

Comment: problem solved without regex buddies :]

Comment: The argument to `String.replaceAll()` *is* a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
String a = b.replaceAll("[Hello 123\\[\\]\\ ]", "")
```

write

```
String a = b.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\ ]", "");
a = a.replace("Hello", "");
a = a.replace("123,", "");
```